# Oreo Foregroundservice the right way

Tags: android, android-service, foreground-service

What is the right way to implement the foregroundservice notification. Call the notification before starting backgroundthread or calling it in the backgroundthread? Tried both ways and it worked the same but what is the right way?

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    //calling notification before backgroundthread
    runAsForeground();

    Runnable service = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //calling notification in backgroundthread
            runAsForeground();
            connect(client,options);

        }
    };

    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(service);
    backgroundThread.start();
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand methode called");

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Call the notification before starting backgroundthread or calling it
>   in the backgroundthread?

As soon as possible, to be more precise, the app must call service's `startForeground()` method within five seconds after the service is created.

So, in your particular situation there's no real reason or benefit in delaying the call by starting it from the Runnable.